# Cannot pass boolean to directive with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I'm trying to pass a boolean value from my controller into my isolated scope directive. When I `console.log(attrs)` from the directive's link function, the `someBoolean` attribute is a string, rendering the actual text "main.bool" instead of a true or false value. When I toggle the boolean value from the outer controller, I want it to be updated in the directive.

https://plnkr.co/edit/80cvLKhFvljnFL6g7fg9?p=preview

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        someBoolean: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'myDirective.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope);
        console.log(attrs);
      },
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        console.log(this);
      },
      controllerAs: 'directiveCtrl',
      bindToController: true
    };
  });
```

Controller

```
   app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.bool = true;
      vm.change = function() {
        vm.bool = !vm.bool;
      }
    });
```

The template

```
<div>
  Inside directive: {{someBoolean}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have attached your directive Controller to `directiveCtrl` instead of `mainCtrl`, you'll access the variable `someBoolean` using `directiveCtrl.someBoolean`.

In this case, change the HTML to:

```
<div>
  Inside directive: {{directiveCtrl.someBoolean}}
</div>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WxxQccvSZmYPwuYn6hHq?p=preview).

Another solution would be to remove the `bindToController` property inside your directive. With this, you don't need to use the controller name before the variable. Working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7rgWyxNHcK3pMxtL6HBA?p=preview).

Read more about this `bindToController` feature [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html).